# What does "though if" mean

Tags: grammar, phrases

I know "as if/as though" means but never heard that sentence starts with "though if".
Can anyone help me with this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

> I never wear a hat and have never bought one. Though if everyone else
> started wearing them I suppose I would.

I would punctuate this sentence by Old Brixtonian as follows:

*I never wear a hat and have never bought one. Though, if everyone else started wearing them, I suppose I would.*

This shows that "though if" is not an idiom, it's just two words used next to each other.

Comment: I used to punctuate too much and have been trying to cut down. But, for my answer, I should have done as you suggest. And you're quite right: "though if" is just two words.

Answer (score 0):

It can only mean the same as "But if" or "Although if". So it must refer to something in the previous sentence. For example:

> I never wear a hat and have never bought one. Though if everyone  else
> started wearing them I suppose I would.

Comment: To clarify a point that Old Brixtonian didn't make explicit: _though if_ is not a phrase in the way that _as if_ is. In their example, _though_ happens to be followed  by a clause beginning with _if_.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Thanks. I should have made that clear. Should I now edit my answer to include your points and chasly's, or leave things as they are?

Comment: Up to you, Old Brick. If you do, I'll then delete my comment.